# How to handle cycles in object graph with yamldotnet serializers

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, yaml, yamldotnet

I'm trying to use Yamldotnet library to serialize a model with circular references. Which serializer settings or data class attributes should I use to achieve this? I want to be able to serialize and deserialize the models back, keeping references.

Sample model:

```cs
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I can serialize the model correctly to yaml:

```
&o0 !Author
Name: name1
Books:
- !Book
  Title: title1
  Authors:
  - *o0
```

, but deserialization throws an exception:

```
YamlDotNet.Core.AnchorNotFoundException: (Line: 7, Col: 5, Idx: 70) - (Line: 7, Col: 8, Idx: 73): Alias $o0 cannot precede anchor declaration
```

[My code sample on .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7w6SM3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was a bug in YamlDotNet library, it should be fixed in the next release following 9.1.4.